# discord.py prefix command

Tags: discord.py

Let's say I don't want to limit myself to a single prefix, and instead use a command to change the prefix to whatever I want for each individual server I'm on.

Basically, there would first be a default prefix, for example `bl!`, and if there was another bot with that prefix, I could do something like `bl!prefix ...`. This would then have the bot read a given text file or json, edit the prefix depending on the guild, and work with that guild and only that guild.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Step 1 - **Set up your json files**:
First you'll want to make a json file. This file will store the information of `message.guild.id` as well as the prefix for that guild. In the picture below, you'll see the json file after it was added to multiple servers. If your bot is already in a large number of servers, you may need to add them manually before you can have an automatic system.
[image: A bot I used with a custom prefix]

Step 2 - **Define get_prefix**: When you're setting up your discord.py bot, you will usually come across a line of code stating the `command_prefix` of the bot. To have a custom prefix, you will first need to define `get_prefix`, which will read from the json file you would have made before.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
def get_prefix(client, message): ##first we define get_prefix
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: ##we open and read the prefixes.json, assuming it's in the same file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json as prefixes
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)] #recieve the prefix for the guild id given
```

Step 3 - **Your bots command_prefix**: This is to ensure your bot has a prefix. Instead of using `command_prefix = "bl!"`, you'll be using your previously defined `get_prefix`.

```py
client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= (get_prefix),
    )
```

Step 4 - **Joining and leaving servers**: All this does is manipulate `prefixes.json`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild): #when the bot joins the guild
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: #read the prefix.json file
        prefixes = json.load(f) #load the json file

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = 'bl!'#default prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f: #write in the prefix.json "message.guild.id": "bl!"
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4) #the indent is to make everything look a bit neater

@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild): #when the bot is removed from the guild
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f: #read the file
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id)) #find the guild.id that bot was removed from

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f: #deletes the guild.id as well as its prefix
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

Step 5 - **Change Prefix Command**:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) #ensure that only administrators can use this command
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix): #command: bl!changeprefix ...
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f: #writes the new prefix into the .json
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f'Prefix changed to: {prefix}') #confirms the prefix it's been changed to
#next step completely optional: changes bot nickname to also have prefix in the nickname
    name=f'{prefix}BotBot'

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Edit: This is for any issues you may come across while using this.

[How do I use `commands.when_mentioned` with this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386984/discord-py-commands-when-mentioned-not-working-with-custom-prefix)

[Why do I get an error whenever someone DMs my bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333249/discord-py-error-message-whenever-user-dms-bot)

[How do I get my bot to respond when mentioned with the guild's set prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70470132/discord-py-getting-bot-to-respond-when-mentioned-but-with-individual-guild-set-p)

Comment: Great , you answered yourself but i think creating a database like mongodb will be better as it will reduce the load on your IDE . Just a tip , best of luck