# How to get the prefix of a server when the bot is mentioned? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**What im trying to do:** I have a custom prefix system similar to this one: [discord.py prefix command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513680/discord-py-prefix-command) And this is my event for when my bot is mentioned:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user.mentioned_in(message):

    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Hello! my prefix is `{prefix}`")
   
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

  await client.process_commands(message)
```

So i want my bot to respond with the prefix for that server.

**My problem:** I don't know how i can read the json file and get the prefix.

Comment: What have you tried yet? I'm assuming that you don't know where to start. Is that the case?

Comment: I tried this: https://pastebin.com/qUpRQRCZ But i couldn't get that to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom prefixes to your bot, you can store the prefix data in a JSON file. You should create a file named `prefixes.json` and 3 commands/events: An event to set a default prefix when the bot joins a server, an event to remove the prefix information from the `prefixes.json` file, and also a command to *change* the bot's prefix.

Here is how you can write the first event: the event that defines a default prefix when the bot joins a guild:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = 'GG'

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

And this is a way you can write the event to *remove* the prefix data from the JSON file when the bot is removed from a server:

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

And finally, here is how you can define the function to change the prefix of the bot. The command will be named `changeprefix`, and you can use it by typing `[prefix]changeprefix` ( replace `[prefix]` to your bot's prefix ). :

```
async def changeprefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
```

You'll also need a command to *find* the prefix corresponding to the guild your bot is in. It's a simple function you can define just like this:

```
def get_prefix(client=None, message=None):
    with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    try:
        prefix = str(message.guild.id)
        return prefixes[prefix]
    except AttributeError:
        return ['defaultPrefix']
```

Now, the last step to this is to integrate those four commands into your bot variable you defined to run other commands. Here is how you should change the `prefix` statement:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But i already have custom prefixes. I just want to make it that if the bot get mentioned it sends the prefix of that particular guild.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. Here is a pastebin code: https://pastebin.com/9PZtTAaN. Does that help you?

Comment: Thank you very much!