# Show data from .json in Discord.py

Tags: json, discord.py

I'm making a bot with custom prefixes on each different server, and i want to make a command that shows the prefix for the server they type the command, my json looks like this :

```
{
    "863801417105014785": "l.",
    "642736426374602346": "b.",
    "387468726374623439": "t."
}
```

i also got the custom prefixes code from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513680/discord-py-prefix-command) i hope it can help

this is the code i have tried

```
@client.command()
async def prf(ctx):
    try:
        with open('./config/prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prfxs = json.load(f())[0]
        await ctx.message.send(data['guild.id'])
    except IOError:
        return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic error in your code. `data['guild.id']` will not spit you out anything as it is not defined in your code. You have to work with `prfxs` as this is your JSON-file.

**New command/code:**

```py
        with open('./config/prefixes.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp: # Open the JSON-file/folder
            cprefix = json.load(fp) # Load the JSON-file
        try:
            prefix = cprefix[f"{ctx.guild.id}"] # Get the data for the guild.id
            await ctx.send(f'My prefix for this server is **{prefix}**') # Display the prefix
        except KeyError:
            return
```