# Discord py Getting bot to respond when mentioned but with individual guild set prefixes

Tags: json, discord, discord.py, bots

So I have my prefix setup so each guild can separately change it doing a command.
I want to be able to mention the bot and it respond with "My prefix is:" but also respond to commands called using the set prefix.
Currently if I add the when

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
  with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

def Mentioned_prefix(client, message):
    prefix = get_prefix(client.message)
    return commands.when_mentioned_or(f'{prefix}')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = Mentioned_prefix, intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
  with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '%'
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
       
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
  with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix
    with open('prefixes.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)
      await ctx.send(f'Prefix is now: {prefix}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        prefix = get_prefix(client, message)
        await message.channel.send(f"Prefix is:' {prefix} '")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a separate function to get a guild's prefix. You can check if a guild's id is in your 'prefixes.json' file, then return this. A further explanation can be found in the code below.

```py
def prefix_check(guild):
    # Check if this is a dm instead of a server
    # Will give an error if this is not added (if guild is None)
    if guild == None:
        return "!"
    try:
        # Check if the guild id is in your 'prefixes.json'
        with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
            prefixes = json.load(f)
            p = prefixes[str(guild.id)]
    except:
        # Otherwise, default to a set prefix
        p = "!"
    # If you're confident that the guild id will always be in your json,
    # feel free to remove this try-except block

    return p

# on_message event
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        # This is how you call the prefix_check function. It takes a guild object
        await message.channel.send(f"My prefix is {prefix_check(message.guild)}")
    
    # Don't forget to process, otherwise your commands won't work!
    await client.process_commands(message)

# In a command (using ctx), do use prefix_check(ctx.guild) to get the guild's prefix
```

[image: Working image]

Comment: Yeah im still struggling am i getting rid off the **def get_prefix** completely.
Also which way would be the best on adding the **prefix_check** to a command ?
Sorry I normally can figure these things out but this one has me banging my head against a wall

Comment: @GremGrem Like I said in my codeblock, in a command you can use `prefix_check(ctx.guild)` wherever you'd like, similarly to how you'd use this in your `on_message` event, just a 'change' of guild.