# Discord py interactive multi-page reaction embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, embed

The following is a **discord.py cog** for a multi-page embed you can interact with using emoji reactions.

---

**IMPORTS:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import asyncio
from asyncio import sleep
```

---

**START OF COG:**

```
def RandomColor(): #generates a random discord colour that will be used in the embeds
  randcolor = discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))
  return randcolor

class Info(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
    print('Info cog working')
```

---

**ACTUAL COMMAND CODE:**

```
  @commands.command()
  async def help(self, ctx):
#First page of embeds **make sure to call each embed a different name**
      emInfo = discord.Embed(title='Info Commands', color=RandomColor())
      emInfo.add_field(name='who', value='gets user info')
      emInfo.add_field(name='ping', value='gets bot speed')

#Second page of embeds
      emMod = discord.Embed(title='Mod Commands', color=RandomColor())
      emMod.add_field(name='kick', value='kicks member')
      emMod.add_field(name='ban', value='bans member')

#Group all the embeds to a single phrase to call on later
      contents = [
        emInfo,
        emMod
      ]
#Pages: How many pages you want
#Cur_page: Tells you what your current page is. **1 = when command is called it starts on 1**
#message: sends the above and embeds in a message **Make sure embed=contents** 
      pages = 2
      cur_page = 1
      message = await ctx.send(
                    content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}\n**Only caller can change page**",
                    embed=contents[cur_page - 1]
      )


#Tells bot to add the following reaction emojis to above message just sent
      await message.add_reaction("◀️")
      await message.add_reaction("▶️")

#Check function so only the command caller can interact with the embed
      def check(reaction, user):
          return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]


      while True:
          try:
#**timeout=None** No time limit if no reaction
#**timeout=60** If no reaction after 60 seconds message will delete 
              reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=None, check=check)


              if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                  cur_page += 1
                  await message.edit(
                      content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}\n**Only caller can change page**",
                      embed=contents[cur_page - 1]
                  )
                  await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

              elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                  cur_page -= 1
                  await message.edit(
                      content=f"Page {cur_page}/{pages}\n**Only caller can change page**",
                      embed=contents[cur_page - 1]
                  )
                  await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

              else:
                  await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
              await message.delete()
              break
```

---

**END OF COG**

```
def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Info(client))
```

If you can see anything i can improve on please let me know :)
What would you like to see next?...

1. A multi server levelling system using json file as a database
2. A multi server individually changeable prefix using json file as a database
3. A multi server Economy games system using json file as a database

Comment: Hey there GremGrem! Do you have a question? If you're only asking how you could improve this code, I recommend visiting [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead, as StackOverflow is targeted towards asking questions. Happy coding!

Comment: @Bagle 
Hi, the post is mainly sharing some code to help others if needed. The statement "If you can see anything I can improve on" is just an addition to the post to see if anyone could help better my code and layout. Hope this post is still okay?... If not I will take it down.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response. A common practice on StackOverflow would be to create a question as if you were asking it, then answer the question with your own answer. You can think of it as a "Q&A" format. I've done this once before, with my question [discord.py prefix command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64513680/14420546) if you'd like to take a look at an example. It helps users find answers to their questions faster if they're looking for this. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, do not use, **DO NOT**, use Json as database. Prefer SQLite, or any database language. I think this explanation by *vcokltfre#6868* on the python discord server is enough to understand why:

1. JSON, quite simply, is not a database. It's not designed to be a data storage format, rather a way of transmitting data over a network. It's also often used as a way of doing configuration files for programs.
2. There is no redundancy built in to JSON. JSON is just a format, and Python has libraries for it like json and ujson that let you load and dump it, sometimes to files, but that's all it does, write data to a file. There is no sort of DBMS (Database Management System), which means no sort of sophistication in how the data is stored, or built in ways to keep it safe and backed up, there's no built in encryption either - bear in mind in larger applications encryption may be necessary for GDPR/relevant data protection regulations compliance.
3. JSON, unlike relational databases, has no way to store relational data, which is a very commonly needed way of storing data. Relational data, as the name may suggest, is data that relates to other data. For example if you have a table of users and a table of servers, the server table will probably have an owner field, where you'd reference a user from the users table. [This is only relevant for relational data]
4. JSON is primarily a KV (key-value) format, for example {"a":"b"} where a is the key and b is the value, but what if you want to search not by that key but by a sub-key? Well, instead of being able to quickly use var[key], which in a Python dictionary has a constant return time (for more info look up hash tables), you now have to iterate through every object in the dictionary and compare to find what you're looking for. Most relational database systems, like MySQL, MariaDB, and PostgreSQL have ways of indexing secondary fields apart from the primary key so that you can easily search by multiple attributes.